# Was bedeutet "Heftfolgen"?

Tags: translation, meaning

Ich fand "Heftfolgen" als Namen einer Mappe mit digitalen Büchern. Was bedeutet es? Das Wort befindet sich in keinen gängigen Wörterbüchern.

Answer (score 8):

Sequence of volumes/issues of magazines.

Say, a monthly magazine is published "Hefte zur Zeitgeschichte"; you might have 12 issues for 2013 bound in one 'volume' titled "HzZ Heftfolgen (or Heftfolge) 2013".

Comment: Das macht Sinn. Vielen Dank.

Comment: np. aber ich bevorzuge das unanglizierte "das _ergibt_ Sinn"  ;-)

Comment: Auch schön: das *stiftet* Sinn :)